# Mapbox + Unity + ARCore

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I am using this Project 
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ar-unity

I think this is more of a Mapbox question then anything.
How do I add a custom 3D Model to the Map. I am not making a Pokemon GO app but as an example say I wanted to add a character to the map in a location how would I add it? I've looked through the modifiers and cannot seem to figure out how to add anything other then pre-existing buildings in the map using its low poly building perimeter.

I did try and use the Conversions.GeoToWorldPosition to place it in a place but even outside it is always off at least in 3d space. using this function in 3d on the map works just fine.

Am I suppose to use the online Mapbox Studio to create a location then the modifiers to place that object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your 3D object by using the POINT OF INTEREST in Abstract Map Script in ArAlignedMap using the WorldAlignmentKit. This kit is address automatically when you choose WorldScale-AR in Mapbox Setup.

For the POI, it can automatically pulled from Mapbox POI database or you may specify custom address or latitude, longitude.